# Can't set keyboard focus to a TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm using the System.Windows.Controls namespace to create a ContextMenu with a number of MenuItems.  One of the MenuItems contains a TextBox as its header that, when clicked, should be given keyboard focus so the user can type in it to specify a config setting.  It successfully detects a mouse click, but what baffles me is that I can't set keyboard focus on it.  I've tried everything that I've seen online with unfortunately little success.

The code below shows the different methods I've attempted to give it keyboard focus.  I was able to get logical focus with only one of the functions, but nothing could set keyboard focus properly.  I've also tried all of these functions on the TextBox's parent, specifyItem, but nothing was different.

```
//*Upon catching a mouse click event:*

MenuItem specifyItem = //MenuItem sent by the event;
TextBox specifyBox = //specifyItem's header;

bool hasLogicalFocus; //store results of attempting logical focus
bool hasKeyboardFocus; //store results of attempting keyboard focus

//attempt UIElement.Focus(); fails both
specifyBox.Focus();
hasLogicalFocus = specifyBox.IsFocused; //false
hasKeyboardFocus = specifyBox.IsKeyboardFocused; //false

//attempt Keyboard.Focus(specifyBox); fails both
Keyboard.ClearFocus(); // <-- did not make a difference
Keyboard.Focus(specifyBox);
hasLogicalFocus = specifyBox.IsFocused; //false
hasKeyboardFocus = specifyBox.IsKeyboardFocused; //false

//attempting asynchronous with dispatcher; fails both
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate ()
{
    specifyBox.Focus();         // Set Logical Focus
    Keyboard.Focus(specifyBox); // Set Keyboard Focus
}));
hasLogicalFocus = specifyBox.IsFocused; //false
hasKeyboardFocus = specifyBox.IsKeyboardFocused; //false

/*This actually does set logical focus, but this isn't 
 * helpful because I need keyboard focus
 */
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(specifyItem, specifyBox);
hasLogicalFocus = specifyBox.IsFocused; //true!
//still doesn't have keyboard focus
```

I expect the keyboard focus of specifyBox to be set to true so that the user can type in it, but the bool specifyBox.IsKeyboardFocused is always false after these operations, and it does not catch any keys from the keyboard.